# Time exceeds when trying to rank int in array

Tags: c++, timeout

I have the following task. Read several objects and print the ranking of the first object read. The ranking of an object o in a set S is plus one to the number of objects greater than the object:

```
R(o, S) = |{e ∈ S | e > o}| + 1
```

For example, if seven numbers are given, say `S = {4, 1, 2, 5, 3, 1, 6}`, as input, the ranking of the first number 4 is 3, namely `R(4, S) = 3`, since there are two numbers (5 and 6) which are greater than 4.

[image: there is entire problem]

I think I have to figure out if the input is int or string so in main I use if. But it makes repetition which probably causes time exceed. I believe the logic part of the code is correct - the output is probably right.

Here is my code:

```cpp
template <class T>
class RankingBag {
    vector<T> v;
    int val;
public:
    RankingBag(): val(1) {}
    void Pushback(T obj);
    T Elem(int i);
    int Ranking(T obj);
    void clear() {
        v.clear();
    }
};

template <class T>
void RankingBag<T>::Pushback(T obj) {
    v.push_back(obj);
}


template <class T>
T RankingBag<T>::Elem(int i) {
    return v[i];
}

template <class T>
int RankingBag<T>::Ranking(T obj) {
    
    for (int i =1;i<v.size();i++) {
        if (v[i] > obj) {
            val++;
        }
    }
    return val;
}

int main() {
    
    string s;
    while (1) {
        getline(cin,s);
        if (isdigit(s.back())) {
            RankingBag<int> r;
            string ss;
            istringstream ins(s);
            
            while (ins >> ss) {
            
                int n;
                stringstream plz;
                plz << ss;
                plz >> n;
            
                r.Pushback(n);
            }
            int num;
            num = r.Elem(0);
            cout << r.Ranking(num) << endl;
            r.clear();
        }
        else {
            RankingBag<string> r;
            string ss;
            istringstream ins(s);
            while (ins >> ss) {
                r.Pushback(ss);
            }
            ss = r.Elem(0);
            cout << r.Ranking(ss) << endl;
            r.clear();
        }

    }
    
}
```

Comment: This is trivial, and does not need to use any vector, or anything like that. All that needs to be done is to read the first number, then read all remaining numbers and simply count how many are greater than the first number. This is about 5-6 lines of code. Mission accomplished.

Comment: Pushback, Elem, Ranking must be there 

I accidentally omitted the contents.

Comment: The ranking is possible with what Sam said. If your problem statement is incomplete, you should edit your question and complete it. Otherwise, from your picture (which is not recommened; put all relevant items in your question as text), it seems like the rank is the only thing that's needed.